# Dynamically adding text boxes in JQueryMobile UI.

Tags: jquery, forms, html, jquery-mobile

Currently I have a JQueryMobile form which has 2 text boxes but there might be scenarios where I have to add couple of more text boxes. How to achieve this?? ...

for example user will click an add button in the screen and it'll bring up a new text box in the screen. I've tried to append but its not working properly.

How to achieve this by dynamically adding text boxes to the JQueryMobile Form??

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: I haven't tried using jquery mobile ui yet. Is the code different from how you do it in jquery?

Comment: logic should be same as jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You said on your comment that logic should be the same with jquery. In jquery I do something like this to create new form elements:

```
//element where you are going to append your dynamically created element
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body'); 

//create textbox and append it to the body of the document.
$('<input>').attr({'type' : 'text', 'placeholder' : 'some text'}).appendTo(body);
```